# PLY Syntax error after creating variable assigment

Tags: python, ply

So I'm new to PLY and I'm trying to understand it. Right now I'm encountering this problem. When the NAME token is defined as a specified raw string, it works. Let's say I define my NAME token as t_NAME='a', then it would work. However, when I use regex, it brakes the rest of the statements I'm using in the parser.

Here's my code:

```
import ply.lex as lex
import ply.yacc as yacc

tokens =('LPAREN','RPAREN','STRING','SHOW', 'NAME', 'IS')

t_LPAREN ='\('
t_RPAREN = '\)'
t_STRING = r'\".*?\"'
t_SHOW = r'show'
t_ignore = " \t"
t_IS = r'is'


def t_NAME(t):
  r"[a-zA-Z]+\w*"
  return t

def t_error(t):
  print("Syntax error at %s"%t.value)

Variables = {}

def p_show(p):
  '''statement : SHOW LPAREN STRING RPAREN
  | SHOW LPAREN NAME RPAREN'''
  value = p.slice[3]

  if value.type == 'NAME':
    print(Variables[value.value])
  else:
    print(value.value)

def p_is(p):
  'statement : NAME IS STRING'
  Variables[p[1]] = p[3]

def p_variable(p):
  'statement : NAME'
  return Variables[p.slice[1].value]

def p_error(p):
  print("Syntax error at %s"%p.value)

lex.lex()
yacc.yacc()
s ='MY_STRING is "this is a string"'
yacc.parse(s)
```

Now, the output is:

```
Generating LALR tables
Syntax error at is
```

I'm not sure what the problem is, I imagine it has to do with using regex, since for example I changed the token IS to r"\=", then variable assigment would work completely fine.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is explained in the [Ply documentation](https://www.dabeaz.com/ply/ply.html), specifically in the section [Specification of Tokens](https://www.dabeaz.com/ply/ply.html#ply_nn6), which is worth reading with care. In summary, the regexes in your specification are handled in the following order:

> 1. All tokens defined by functions are added in the same order as they appear in the lexer file.
> 2. Tokens defined by strings are added next by sorting them in order of decreasing regular expression length (longer expressions are added first).

That means that your `NAME` regex is matched before the `IS` regex is tried, making it impossible for `IS` to match.

The manual also provides sample code for the recommended approach to handle reserved words:

> To handle reserved words, you should write a single rule to match an identifier and do a special name lookup in a function like this:
>
> ```py
>    reserved = {
>       'if' : 'IF',
>       'then' : 'THEN',
>       'else' : 'ELSE',
>       'while' : 'WHILE',
>       ...
>    }
>
>    tokens = ['LPAREN','RPAREN',...,'ID'] + list(reserved.values())
>
>    def t_ID(t):
>        r'[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*'
>        t.type = reserved.get(t.value,'ID')    # Check for reserved words
>        return t
> ```

Not only does this solve the regex ordering problem, but it is also much more efficient, and easier to maintain. Although you could force the correct order by  using a separate function and  regex for each keyword, that would force all of these patterns to be attempted for every token match.

It would also require a lot of boilerplate code. The recommended approach requires only a single key and value to be added to a dictionary for each reserved word.

Comment: Ah yes, I saw a similar answers to a similar response on another post but I didn't quite understand. Now I moved tokens defined by words (like 'show' and 'is') to the reserved dictionary and it works perfectly. Thank you so much for the detailed and simple to understand answer!